# Extract `m`th (first) column value for line with specific `n`th (second) column value from file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to Write an `awk` command that will return the identification number from the following table for only the lines where the title is `Turtle`. This table is stored in `turtle.txt`

```
Id Num. Title           CatchDate
433417  RedTurtle       2001-06-29
493303  BlueTurtle      1998-09-20
259497  Turtle          1985-05-08
229505  RedTurtle       1994-07-13
473076  OrangeTurtle    2002-03-08
221907  Blueturtle      1999-07-02
457032  Turtle          1993-04-09
490359  RedTurtle       1996-11-12
494595  SnappingTurtle  1985-05-20
402421  BlueTurtle      1999-08-16
```

Comment: @simlev, the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) algorithm is a mystery; it's contributing to the views & votes here

Comment: Hi Kamat. I generalized the title of your question. The answer would be the same if this was about, say, a part number / description / price table, so the fact that it's about animals in this case seems inconsequential to answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
$ awk '$2 == "Turtle" {print $1}' turtle.txt
259497
457032
```

- `$2` is the field to select.
- `Turtle` is the text to match.
- `{print $1}` is to print the first field.
- `turtle.txt` is the name of the source file.

With sed:

```
$ <infile sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/\n/g;/([^\n]+\n){1}Turtle/([^\n]*).*/\1/;p};d'
```

Explained:

- `<infile` Source file
- `sed -E` Use sed with POSIX ERE (Extended Regular Expresions)
- `'s/[[:blank:]]+/\n/g` Replace all (runs `+`) of tab-space with a new line.
- `/([^\n]+\n){1}Turtle\n/` If field `n` (use `n-1` here) match `Turtle` (exactly).
- `([^\n]*).*/\1/` Extract field 1 (first line)
- `p};d'` Print what was selected and delete everything in any case.

**General solution for any pair of field(s) `n` and `m`:**

```
<infile sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/\n/g;/([^\n]+\n){1}Turtle/{s/([^\n]+\n){0}([^\n]*).*/\2/;p};d'
```

- `<infile` Source file
- `sed -E '` For sed with ERE regexes.
- `s/[[:blank:]]+/\n/g` Break all input into lines at (runs of) tabs or spaces.
- `/([^\n]+\n){1}Turtle/` If the pattern space match the `n`th field (use `n-1` (`{1}`) here).
- `{` Start a sequence of commands.
- `s/` Start a replace (a `s///` command).
- `([^\n]+\n){0}` Match `m-1` (`{0}`) lines (for field `m`).
- `([^\n]*)` Capture the field (the line) to keep in backreference `\2`.
- `.*` And match everything else (in the pattern space (the original line)).
- `/\2/` Replace all of above (The pattern space) with what was captured in `\2`.
- `;p};` Print it. And close command sequence.
- `d` In any case, delete the pattern space, start again.
- `'` End sed command.

Comment: Note that the `sed` one assumes GNU `sed` 4.2+ and that POSIXLY_CORRECT not be in the environment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
awk '$2 == "Turtle" {print $1}' file
259497
457032
```

Answer (score 3):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/\sTurtle\s/s/^\([0-9]\+\)\s.*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: Of course this would match “Turtle” appearing in any column except for the first or the last.  (Of course, for a three-column file, that does narrow it down to the second column — but it will fail on a line where the third column is missing.)   And, of course, it depends on the ID number being *purely* numeric.  Some people use things like “123.01”, “456A”, “78(9)” and “987-65-4321” as ID “numbers”.

Answer (score 2):

non-awk alternative:

`grep -w "Turtle" turtle.txt | cut -d " " -f 1`

Comment: But this would match “Turtle” (or even something like ‘‘Turtle#1998’’ or ‘‘Mock-Turtle’’) appearing in any column.

Answer (score 2):

[Golfing it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf):

```
$ awk '$2=="Turtle"&&$0=$1' <file
259497
457032
```

Or, expanded in stages until we reach Isaac's and Goro's answers

```
awk '$2 == "Turtle" && $0 = $1' <file

awk '$2 == "Turtle" { $0 = $1; print }' <file

awk '$2 == "Turtle" { print $1 }' <file
```

The three are not *exactly* equivalent as my golfed code would not print the number if it was zero (the result of `$0=$1` is used as a conditional).

---

Here's a proper `sed` solution to make up for the golfing above:

```
$ sed -n '/\<Turtle\>/s/[[:blank:]].*//p' <file
259497
457032
```

It finds all lines containing the word `Turtle` and then remowes the first space or tab character and everything after it on those lines before printing them (printing of other lines is inhibited by `-n`).

The `\<` and `\>` matches word start and end boundaries so that `\<Turtle\>` matches only the string `Turtle` and not e.g. `RedTurtle`.

Comment: The first one won't work properly when the id is zero

Comment: @user000001 This was already made clear in the answer.

Comment: But it adds nothing useful IMO. That's more of an example of things *not* to do (use assignments as conditions in `awk`).

Comment: Note that `\<Turtle\>` is not portable and would match on Red-Turtle. You would need something like `sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}Turtle\([[:blank:]].*\)\{0,1\}$/\1/p'` for a real equivalent.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Also, of course, your `sed` solution would match “Turtle” appearing in any column.

Comment: @G-Man Absolutely. I mentioned this. "Any line containing the word".

Comment: The only way to make the golfed idea work correctly even if the value of `$2` is zero is to use: `awk '{a=$2;$0=$1}a=="Turtle"'` but that is just one character longer than `awk '$2=="Turtle"{print $1}', so, no, you win no cigar. Maybe you will like to take a look at the general sed solution I wrote (in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You may employ `grep` in this:

```
 grep -oP '^\d+(?=\h+Turtle\h)'
```

Comment: We expect answers as complex/cryptic as this  to include an explanation.